# Using datetime in order to name files

Tags: python, datetime

I have a script that makes use of `datetime` in order to name files.

Only business days (Mon - Fri) are used.

Here is my part of the code that finds the last business day:

```
lastBusDay = datetime.datetime.today()
shift = datetime.timedelta(max(1,(lastBusDay.weekday() + 6) % 7 - 3))
lastBusDay = lastBusDay - shift
yesterday = lastBusDay.strftime('%d%m%y')
```

These variables are outside of any function and are the first part of my script after the `imports`. I've heard that global variables are bad, and I understand why.

But does this fall under the same category?

Only the `yesterday` variable is used later on in the script and is used to specify the new name in an the `os.renames` function.

Answer (score 2):

I think you only want to calculate the last working day from today. Here is a better/pythonic approach:

```
from datetime import timedelta, date

def lastBzDay( d = None ):
  r, d = xrange( 1, 5 ), d or date.today()
  def retfn( curDay = d ):
    w = curDay.weekday()
    prevBzDay = curDay - timedelta( days= 1 if w in r else (w + 3) % 7 )
    return prevBzDay.strftime('%d%m%y')
  return retfn
lastBzDay = lastBzDay()
```

Now, all you have to do is:

```
yesterday = lastBzDay()
```

and you'll get the desired result. Using a closure also gives you the ability to find the last weekday from any other dates:

```
print lastBzDay( date(2014, 9, 7) )  # will give you 050914
```

You can see a demo on [codepad here](http://codepad.org/XU1IszRX).

Comment: I may be using this wrong or it might be an error, I'm not sure, but when doing `print lastBzDay` it is returning `<function retfn at 0x00B915B0>`

Comment: @JoeSmart `lastBzDay` is a closure. It returns a function in its first call. This is wy I've put `lastBzDay = lastBzDay()` just after defining the function.

Comment: I have that in my script. I do `lastBzDay = lastBzDay()` and then `print lastBzDay`

Comment: @JoeSmart The first call returns another function, which has access to the local variable `r = xrange`. I only used this so that I won't have to compute `xrange` every time the function is called.